# Memory Allocation Time (The Fast Way)

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, clr

For a really simple code snippet, I'm trying to see how much of the time is spent actually allocating objects on the small object heap (SOH).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int noNumbers = 10000000;  // 10 mil

        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
        Random random = new Random(1);  // use the same seed as to make
                                        //  benchmarking consistent
        for (int i = 0; i < noNumbers; i++)
        {
            int currentNumber = random.Next(10);  // generate a non-negative
                                                  //  random number less than 10
            object o = currentNumber;  // BOXING occurs here
            numbers.Add(o);
        }
    }
```

In particular, I want to know how much time is spent allocating space for the all the boxed `int` instances on the heap (I know, this is an `ArrayList` and there's horrible boxing going on as well - but it's just for educational purposes).

The CLR has 2 ways of performing memory allocations on the SOH: either calling the `JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP` (for multi-processor systems, `...SFastSP` for single processor ones) allocation helper - which is really fast since it consists of a few assembly instructions - or failing back to the slower `JIT_New` allocation helper.

PerfView sees just fine the `JIT_New` being invoked:
[image]

However, I can't figure out which - if any - is the native function involved for the "quick way" of allocating. I certainly don't see any `JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP`. I've already tried raising the count of the loop (from 10 to 500 mil), in the hope of increasing my chances of of getting a glimpse of a few stacks containing the elusive function, but to no avail.

Another approach was to use JetBrains dotTrace (line-by-line) performance viewer, but it falls short of what I want: I do get to see the approximate time it takes the boxing operation for each `int`, but 1) it's just a bar and 2) there's both the allocation itself and the copying of the value (of which the latter is not what I'm after).
[image]

Using the JetBrains dotTrace Timeline viewer won't work either, since they currently don't (quite) support native callstacks.

At this point it's unclear to me if there's a method being dynamically generated and called when `JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP` is invoked - and by miracle neither of the PerfView-collected stack frames (one every 1 ms) ever capture it -, or somehow the `Main`'s method body gets patched, and those few assembly instructions mentioned above are somehow injected directly in the code. It's also hard to believe that the fast way of allocating memory is never called.

You could ask "But you already have the .NET Core CLR code, why can't you figure out yourself ?". Since the .NET Framework CLR code is not publicly available, I've looked into its sibling, the .NET Core version of the CLR (as Matt Warren recommends in his step 6 [here](https://mattwarren.org/2018/03/23/Exploring-the-internals-of-the-.NET-Runtime/)). The `\src\vm\amd64\JitHelpers_InlineGetThread.asm` file contains a `JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP_InlineGetThread` function. The issue is that parsing/understanding the C++ code there is above my grade, and also I can't really think of a way to "Step Into" and see how the JIT-ed code is generated, since this is way lower-level that your usual Press-F11-in-Visual-Studio.

**Update 1**: Let's simplify the code, and only consider individual boxed `int` values:

```
        const int noNumbers = 10000000;  // 10 mil

        object o = null;
        for (int i=0;i<noNumbers;i++)
        {
            o = i;
        }
```

Since this is a Release build, and dead code elimination could kick in, WinDbg is used to check the final machine code.

The resulting JITed code, whose main loop is highlighted in blue below, which simply does repeated boxing, shows that the method that handles the memory allocation is not inlined (note the `call` to hex address `00af30f4`):
[image]

This method in turn tries to allocate via the "fast" way, and if that fails, goes back to the "slow" way of a `call` to `JIT_New` itself):
[image]

It's interesting how the call stack in PerfView obtained from the code above doesn't show any intermediary method between the level of `Main` and the `JIT_New` entry itself (given that `Main` doesn't directly `call` `JIT_New`):
[image]

Comment: `I want to know how much time is spent allocating space for the all the boxed`... Can't you use a stopwatch, start it before `object o = currentNumber;` and then stop it after `object o = currentNumber;`. then when done, look at the `ElapsedTicks` property... Then use the `Frequency` field to convert these ticks into actual seconds if you want.

Comment: I'm thinking of the GC kicking in, both the blocking as well as the background one (for gen0/1 at least) which might skew the results. The callstacks on the other hand wouldn't lie - provided they're taken often enough - but if there's no function called for the slow path, then there's really nothing to see.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a possibility, but TMK I am not sure otherwise how to avoid this. Maybe someone else can chime in on this.

Comment: @MihaiAlbert: Callstacks can certainly lie. The "JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP" method might be inlined.

Comment: @Idov: I've went ahead and checked with WinDbg, and it appears that it doesn't get inlined. I've also updated the question with my latest findings.